# About Linux C - UUID

Tags: c, linux, uuid

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <uuid/uuid.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    uuid_t uuid;
    int uuid_generate_time_safe(uuid);
    printf("%x",uuid);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I just wonder why uuid is not 16 bytes long?
I use DEBUG to view the memory, It is indeed not 16 bytes.
And I use libpcap to develop my program, The uuid is not unique.

Comment: How are you determining that it's not 16 bytes long?  What happens if you examine `sizeof(uuid)`?  Why aren't you using [`uuid_parse()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/uuid_parse)?

Comment: I'll tell you what's not 16 bytes long.  The argument corresponding with `%x`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth uuid_t = char [16] , it is defined in uuid header file.

Comment: @asveikau I use eclipse to debug the program. the memory viewer displays zero. What shall I do ?

Comment: @asveikau is correct, you need to read the documentation for `printf`.

Comment: @asveikau: The argument corresponding to `%x` *is* 16 bytes long.  `"%x"` just isn't the right format to display it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just tried your program on my system, and `uuid` *is* 16 bytes long.  But your program doesn't display its size.

The line:

```
int uuid_generate_time_safe(uuid);
```

isn't a call to the `uuid_generate_time_safe` function, it's a *declaration* of that function with `uuid` as the (ignored) name of the single parameter. (And that kind of function declaration isn't even valid as of the 1999 standard, which dropped the old "implicit `int`" rule.)

Your `printf` call:

```
printf("%x",uuid);
```

has undefined behavior; `"%x"` requires an argument of type `unsigned int`.

If you look in `/usr/include/uuid/uuid.h`, you'll see that the definition of `uuid_t` is:

```
typedef unsigned char uuid_t[16];
```

The correct declaration of `uuid_generate_time_safe` (see `man uuid_generate_time_safe`) is:

```
int uuid_generate_time_safe(uuid_t out);
```

You don't need that declaration in your own code; it's provided by the `#include <uuid/uuid.h>`.
Because `uuid_t` is an array type, the parameter is really of type `unsigned char*`, which is why the function is seemingly able to modify its argument.

Here's a more correct program that illustrates the use of the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <uuid/uuid.h>

int main(void) {
    uuid_t uuid;
    int result = uuid_generate_time_safe(uuid);
    printf("sizeof uuid = %d\n", (int)sizeof uuid);
    // or: printf("sizeof uuid = %zu\n", sizeof uuid);
    if (result == 0) {
        puts("uuid generated safely");
    }
    else {
        puts("uuid not generated safely");
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof uuid; i ++) {
        printf("%02x ", uuid[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

On my system, I got the following output:

```
sizeof uuid = 16
uuid not generated safely
26 9b fc b8 89 35 11 e1 96 30 00 13 20 db 0a c4
```

See the man page for information about why the "uuid not generated safely" message might appear.

Note that I had to install the `uuid-dev` package to be able to build and run this program.